# Best approach for lazy getter property where other properties depend on it's value

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, model-view-controller, properties

say i have a class Invoice where paiement entries  can be made elsewhere and i must keep other values up to date.

```
class Invoice
{
  public decimal BaseTotal {get;set;}
  public decimal Payed {get {retun JouranlEntries.CalculatePayed(this.Id);}} 
 /* this takes a long time and blocks everything */

  public CurrentTotal {get { return BaseTotal - Payed; }}
  public Taxe // must use latest Payed value
  public InLetters // must use latest Payed value
  // others
}
```

My property '`Payed`' needs to be calculated 'alwayes up to date value' on every `notifypropertyupdate`
turning my UI very very slow

i've tried to create an async method `SetPayedValue()`and populate payed value inside it. but gets called every time i call the object (in tables, charts, reports...)
How can i let a property up to date async and when should i call that `SetPayedValue` method if i must use such  a method .

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Ideally, Getters should not perform calculations. Read [Eric Lippert's blog post about properties](https://ericlippert.com/2014/05/19/when-should-i-write-a-property/), it should give you a few ideas on what to do and more importantly, what not to do.

Comment: And instead of calculating `Payed` every single time, why don't you update it when needed? How is it calculated?

Comment: Minor thing, I think you mean `Paid` not `Payed`.

Comment: Since you are calling other methods, why not pass that value to the `Invoice` ctor?